# Filtering inside a stylus selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, stylus

I have several `.list` elements which all need a red color. Of these `.list` elements, the ones with class `.foo` would need a bigger font, whereas `.bar` would need a smaller font.

In CSS, it would be along the lines of:

```
.list {
  color: red;
}

.list.foo {
  font-size: 150%;
}

.list.bar {
  font-size: 75%;
}
```

Is there a way in Stylus to get this without using `.list` thrice? I know this works:

```
.list
  color red

.list.foo
  font-size 150%

.list.bar
  font-size 75%
```

I would like something like the following instead, so as to make it clearer everything belongs to `.list` elements, with certain constraints (`.foo`, `.bar`) added for specific properties. The following, however, selects descendants instead:

```
.list
  color red

  .foo
    font-size 150%

  .bar
    font-size 75%
```

Is there a syntax in Stylus that allows this kind of structure, i.e. to filter elements inside  `.list`, and apply certain properties to each "branch" (`.list.foo`, `.list.bar`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stylus makes use of `&` to reference the selector in the previous nesting level (the "parent selector"), similarly to [Sass/SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#referencing_parent_selectors_) and [LESS](http://lesscss.org). This is shown in the [Selectors](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/docs/selectors.html) reference for Stylus.

I haven't used Stylus before, but see if the following works for you:

```
.list
  color red

  &.foo
    font-size 150%

  &.bar
    font-size 75%
```